# I want to close this side bar by clicking same button

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  
      
      
     <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle collapsed">
      Home</a>

            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
      
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Sidebar</button>  
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

The sidebar opens the contents when I click the button, and it closes the sidebar when I click the
x mark placed at right to in the sidebar. However I want to close this sidebar using same button when I used to open. However I also want to keep the x mark in the sidebar. I have idea that if the sidebar is opened it can be closed by clicking same button.

Comment: Further to the suggestions below you can simply do the following:
1) Create a sidebar as it should look when it's open.
2) Once the sidebar is ready, create a CSS class with property ```display:none;```
3) Create a function named something like ```toggleSidebar()``` and use ```classList.toggle(<classname created for display:none>)``` method with the classname.
4) In case you want some translation/transition, you can include CSS property like ```left: -<width of the sidebar>``` in the ```CSS class``` that you created in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**,

Here **toggleclass()** used to toggle **open** class while clicking both of one **`☰ Sidebar`** or **`x`** button.

Add new style in css

```
#mySidebar.open{ width:250px; }
#main.open{ margin-left:250px; }
```

Add change in html code

In both of **click()** event call `OpenOrClose()` function.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn text-white" onclick="OpenOrClose()">×</a> 
 <button class="openbtn" onclick="OpenOrClose()">☰ Sidebar</button>
```

Result:

```js
function OpenOrClose() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").classList.toggle("open");
  document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}

#mySidebar.open{width:250px;}
#main.open{margin-left:250px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn text-white" onclick="OpenOrClose()">×</a>
      
     <ul class="list-unstyled bg-info text-white">
        <li>
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle collapsed text-white">
      Home</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Home 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Home 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Home 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#homeSubmenu" class="text-white">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#homeSubmenu" class="text-white">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
      
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="OpenOrClose()">☰ Sidebar</button>  
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle a class instead of change the style properties and doing this you only need a single function, so I called it `toggleNav`.

**New CSS:**

```
#mySidebar.active{
 width: 250px;
}

#main.active{
 margin-left: 250px;
}
```

**New Javascript:**

```
function toggleNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").classList.toggle("active");
  document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Update your HTML by replacing all of your onclicks with: `onclick="toggleNav()"`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a little (and easy) javascript to change the attribute.

In the `openNav()` function, add a line which turns the onclick to `closeNav()`.
Also, add an `id` to the button so that you will be able to change the attribute, specific for the button you want.

```
<button id="btn123" class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Sidebar</button>
<!-- adding id -->

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("btn123").setAttribute("onclick", "closeNav()");
  // add this line to set the attribute

}
```

and also do the opposite: in the `closeNav()` function, set the `onclick` attribute to `openNav()` like this:

```
document.getElementById("btn123").setAttribute("onclick", "openNav()");
```

Answer (score 0):

**use js toggle function**

**add class `toggleBtn` anywhere do you want .. it will work...**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".toggleBtn").forEach(function(el){
 el.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").classList.toggle('width');
    document.getElementById("main").classList.toggle('margin');
    })
 })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}
.width{
  width: 250px;
 
}
.margin{
   margin-left:250px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openbtn toggleBtn" >×</a>
  
      
      
     <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle collapsed">
      Home</a>

            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
      
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn toggleBtn" >☰ Sidebar</button>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @imvain2 said.

Or you can do what @php123 said: change the value of `onclick` property to "closeNav()" when it is clicked to open, and change it to "openNav()" when it is clicked to close.

Let's say your button has id="sideBarBtn"

then,

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  //extra line down here
  document.getElementById("sideBarBtn").setAttribute("onclick" , "closeNav()");
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  //extra line down here
  document.getElementById("sideBarBtn").setAttribute("onclick" , "openNav()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the usage of a helper class in this situation, and by merging both functions into one function named `manageNav()`. Here is an example:

```js
function manageNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width == "0px" || document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width == 0 ? document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px" : document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft == "0px" || document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft == 0 ? document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px" : document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="manageNav()">×</a>



  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle collapsed">
      Home</a>

      <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="manageNav()">☰ Sidebar</button>
</div>
```